# Capistrano Many Private Repo Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, capistrano

Very strange behavior and i cant understand where problems.
I have 2 private repositories on Github and i deploy with Capistrano.
First app normal deployed `deploy.rb`:

```
require "rvm/capistrano"
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rvm_ruby_string, "2.1.0"
set :assets_role, :app
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
set :application, "awesome_app_one"

set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:myaccount/repo_one.git"
set :branch, :master
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }

set :user, "rails"
set :deploy_to, "/home/rails/#{application}"
set :shared_children,   %w(public/system public/files public/uploads log tmp/pids tmp/sockets)
set :use_sudo,  false

task :production do
  role :web, "123.456.789.0"
  role :app, "123.456.789.0"
  role :db,  "123.456.789.0", primary: true

  set :branch, :master
  set :deploy_to, "/home/rails/#{application}"
  set :rails_env, 'production'
end
```

Another app have similar `deploy.rb` recipe and capistrano can`t found repo:

```
> ** [123.456.789.0 :: err] ERROR: Repository not found.
> ** [123.456.789.0 :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Then i try clone repo on server:

```
$> git clone git@github.com:myaccount/repo_two.git
$> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/rails/repo_two/.git/
$> ERROR: Repository not found.
$> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I add my ssh keys from server on `repo_one` and `repo_two`. Look the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111007/cannot-access-private-github-repo) but no answers.

### Update:

I found some [solution](http://blog.aculios.com/post/46815591504/ssh-deployment-keys) and now i can clone repo on server but somebody know how tell capistrano use my command to pull repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this error last night

We had to use this to get around that error:

```
set :repository, 'https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git'
```

We're refactoring, but it worked for us

Comment: i change my `set :repository, "https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git"` and can deploy now. Thank`s

Comment: Good to hear it worked! I'll let you know if we make it more data-sensitive. I amended the answer - if it worked, you should accept

Comment: Have you been able to come up with any other solutions that uses the keys instead of username/password?